# Access denied errors when embedding Youtube into Modal

Tags: jquery, iframe, youtube, modal-dialog

I have a page where users can post Youtube video's to a forum.

After a user posts a link to a video the link is converted to something like this:

```
<a href='javascript:void(0)' class='video_player' data-videoid='http://www.youtube.com/embed/$vidID'>$video_title</a>
```

The $vidID is just the Youtube Video ID that you see in the URL of every youtube video. When the user clicks the link to play the video, a modal is opened with the embedded video in it. Here's the JS for the modal:

```
$('.video_player').live('mouseover', function(event) {//VIDEO PLAYER MODAL
    var videoid = $(this).attr("data-videoid");
    var sourcepage = $(this).attr("data-sourcepage");
    $(this).qtip({
     id: 'videomodal',
     content: {
            text: '<img src="images/loading.gif" alt="Loading..." /> Loading..please wait.',
            ajax: {url: 'modals/video_player.php',type: 'GET',data: { videoid: videoid, sourcepage: sourcepage}},
            title: { text: 'Video Player', button: true }
     },
     position: {    my: 'center', at: 'center', target: $(window) },
     show: { event: 'click', solo: true, modal: true },
     hide: false,
     style: 'ui-tooltip-tipsy ui-tooltip-rounded higher-zindex',
     events: {
        hide: function(event, api){
         auto_refresh = setInterval(function (){$('#bottom_middle').load(thisurl + '&timer=' + new Date().getTime() + ' #bottom_middle' );}, 5000);             
         $(this).qtip("destroy"); 
        }
     },  
    });
return false;
});
```

Here's my code for video_Player.php: (Very basic, the modal loads this page, and embeds the needed iframe to play the video)

```
<?PHP
 $videoid = $_GET['videoid'];
 $sourcepage = $_GET['sourcepage'];

 echo "<iframe title='YouTube video player' width='480' height='390' src='$videoid' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>";   
?>
```

In Chrome I get the "Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL blah blah" error, but the video plays and everything seems to work properly, but in IE I'm getting SCRIPT5: Access is denied.  I've search the web, and this site for a solution, but have had 0 luck.  Anyone know of a work around for this or a better method?  I have use the modal (qtip2), that's the only requirement. All of my jquery libraries are up to date also.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your code:

```
$('iframe').each(function(){
    var url = $(this).attr("src");
    $(this).attr("src",url+"?wmode=transparent");
});
```